# How computes the number of integers from start up to

Tags: python, while-loop

Write a function div_3_5(start, end) that computes the number of integers from start up to, but not including end that are divisible by 3 or 5 using a while loop.

NOTE: I must use a while loop inside a function for this exercise (i understand that a for loop is best).

Examples:
div_3_5(7, 27) evaluates to 9 ( numbers divisible by 3 or 5 in that range: 9,10,12,15,18,20,21,24,25)

I really don't understand why or what I'm doing and can someone to explain where i went wrong. 
This is my code so far:

```
count = 0
def div_3_5(start, end):
    while start < end:
        if start%3 == 0 or start%5 == 0:
            count + 1
        start = start + 1
            start + 1
    return count
```

This obviously isn't complete or correct and the current error I'm getting is:

Expected Output:

div_3_5(7, 27) -> 9

Test Result: 0 != 9

Comment: You are incrementing start outside of the while loop. so the loop start/end values never change meaning it will just loop forever. Take a look at list comprehension. Without solving the problem for you consider something like `[v for v in range(start, end+1) if True]`. Change True to a function that yields True for a v you want and you'll have your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There a few tips that would help here.

1. The mod operation % will return the remainder of an object so it a number is divisible by another the mod will be 0, for example 6 % 3 == 0 returns true.
2. A while loop isn't the best for this opertation, better would be a for loop

`for i in range(start, end+1):`

This wil fix the infinite loop.

This is how I would write it:

```
def div_3_5(start, end):
    count = 0
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
            count += 1
    return count

start = 1
end = 10

count = div_3_5(start, end)
print(count)
```

Comment: I just edited my post now, however i should have noted that I must use a while loop inside a function to pass this exercise

Answer (score 0):

Python has a modulus operator (%) which returns the remainder of A/B (10%4 == 2).

In your case, you would be looking for numbers which have a remainder of 0 when divided by 3 or 5

(i.e x%3 == 0 OR x%5 == 0).

Finally, the last elif where you ask `elif start >= end` is unnecessary because you stated that as the condition when you created the loop. Instead, try replacing those 2 lines with `start = start + 1`

Comment: This was extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

The answer i found was:

```
def div_3_5(start, end):
count = 0
while start < end:
    if start % 3 == int() or start % 5 == int():
        count += 1
    start = start + 1
return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You need no loops to accomplish this task, here is simple -and fun- mathematical method that Python allows us to implement easily:
 - One, create a set from 0 to the end with steps of 3s, i.e. {0,3,6,...end} this will get you all the elements that are divisible 3 within the boundary of your end (while keeping the end not included), in Python, this is done this way: `set_of_3=set(range(0,b,3))` simple eh?
 - Two, do the same but for the 5s, `set_of_5=set(range(0,b,5))`
 - Three, add these sets together: `set_of_all=set_of_3.union(set_of_5)`
Now you got all the elements divisible by 3 and 5 from 0 to end, but you don't want that, you want from beginning to end, simply, just remove all numbers from 0 to your beginning from the `set_of_all`, by: `result = set_of_all - set(range(0,a))` and just return the `len()` of that result. Your complete code:

```
def div_3_5(start,end):
    set_of_3 = set(range(0,end,3))
    set_of_5 = set(range(0,end,5))
    set_of_all = set_of_3.union(set_of_5)
    result = set_of_all - set(range(0,start))
    return len(result)
```

A bit convoluted I know, but fun! At least for me. Hope this helps.

**EDITED**

Yeah I didn't notice you said you must use `while` loop, you can do this version of your code:

```
def div_3_5(start,end):
    list = []
    while start<end:
        if start%3==0 or start%5==0:
            list.append(start)
        start+=1
    return len(list)
```

Use the power of Python and forget these C-ish methods, and regarding what is wrong with your code, the line:
`count + 1` doesn't work in Python, you have to do this: `count+=1`